# How do I get the playlist index in reverse order using youtube-dl?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

There's a playlist with 3012 videos. I want to download the first 100 videos of this playlist, which are actually the 100 most recent videos, so I want `%(playlist_index)s` to start from 3012 to 2913 instead of 1 to 100.

What I have now is just a basic shell script:

```sh
youtube-dl --yes-playlist "www.youtube.com/playlist?list=3xAMpLe_iD" -o "%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --download-archive archive.txt
```

I'd like to keep track of the video order in reverse because the following week there might be 4 new videos then when I download those, the numbering should be 3016 to 3013 because it will come from the same playlist.

I have no experience with youtube-dl python scripts but you may answer as if I know the basics. Also, how can I get the `--download-archive` file named to the `%(playlist)s` value in the same script?

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to do this.

First addressing your reverse problem:
There is a parameter `--playlist-reverse`.
It will use list comprehension `[::-1]` to reverse. This will then download files in a reversed order.
However I am not sure how it's stored even if you use `%(playlist_index)s`.
It may start downloading with let's say `3012` but as this should be the index it will be stored as `3012` but I haven't tested that.
So you may want to use `%(autonumber)s` as it will number your tracks according to the queue order. Note it will start numbering from 1 then.
To avoid that you can specify the start number with `--autonumber-start`

Now to your second problem - starting at the right point.
There is `--playlist-start`.
But you have to tell explicitly where to start. In your case `3012`.
There is `--playlist-end`.
Once again you have to specify it exactly. In your case `2913`.
And ultimately there is `--playlist-items` which is likely what you looking for then.

So your command would look like this

```
youtube-dl --yes-playlist "www.youtube.com/playlist?list=3xAMpLe_iD" -o "%(playlist)s/%(autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --autonumber-start 3012 --playlist-items 100 --download-archive archive.txt
```

Let me know if it works and do what you were looking for.

Comment: Numbering with parameter `--playlist-reverse` is what is expected: last video in the playlist is numbered 01, previous 02, etc. No need to use `%(autonumber)s`.

Comment: @raph82 your comment is confusing because it describes a logical behavior that doesn't exist.  if --playlist-reverse started the chronologically first video with a 1 (for playlist_index right?) then this would all be reasonable and videos would have fixed numbers.  Instead it acts in the insane way and counts backward from the total current number of videos so the indexes are different every time a video is uploaded

Comment: @user1169420 I don't how I can make my comment better. Probably I don't understand 'it describes a logical behavior that doesn't exist'. To me, the fact that --playlist-reverse... reverses the playlist, thus the last item becoming the first one, is very logical. Even if it doesn't do what the OA wants. Any hint as to how to make my comment clearer?

Comment: @raph82 Apologies.  Your comment is very clear and how it *should* work, it's just not the behavior I was observing.  However I just realized the reason why is I have youtube-dl aliased to yt-dlp, a fork, because at some point youtube-dl started downloading things at ~20kbps, but apparently yt-dlp's --playlist-reverse implementation doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy!

I am using yt-dlp, and there is a solution with yt-dlp instead of youtube-dl if you are interested.

- You will want to use `--playlist-start 3012` and `--playlist-end 2913`
- You will want to use `--playlist-reverse`
- As your output string    try `"%(playlist)s/%(playlist_autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s"`

NOTE:  It is important to use `%(playlist_autonumber)s` instead of `%(playlist_index)s`.  Playlist_index will number them the same, but DOWNLOAD in reverse order.  This is not what you want, you want to NUMBER them in reverse.

Here is a bug report on github explaining the same problem you had.
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/pull/302

The developer added playlist_autonumber and closed the bug report.  It works fine now.  An example command to download playlist items 2913-3012 from a youtube channel would be something like this:

```
yt-dlp -f 'bv*[height<=1440]+ba' --embed-thumbnail --embed-metadata --download-archive archive.txt --playlist-reverse --playlist-start 3012 --playlist-end 2913 https://www.youtube.com/@YouTubeChannel/videos -o '%(channel)s/%(playlist_autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

I downloaded from the entire youtube channel instead of just a playlist, but it should work either way.  For the channel use

`%(channel)s/%(playlist_autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s`

and for the playlist use

`%(channel)s/%(playlist_autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s`

Good luck man!